# What should I use to make scrollable text area (no-editable) with icons (.png) in each line?

Tags: actionscript-3, icons, textarea

Which Flash Component should I use? DataGrid, ScrollPane, TextArea?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how are icons supposed to be placed in the lines.
anyway *imho* the best choice is to write a custom class that'd extended `Sprite` and was a wrapper for a `TextField`